# Special Characters Must Be Escaped error in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

Am playing with a bootstrap template and came across this error on one of the lines in Dreamweaver which I do not understand. The line of code is:

```
<a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Start Bootstrap</a>
```

Everything works fine in a browser so it's not a site killer but I don't understand what the problem is. Tried putting quotes around the "$("#menu-close").click();" but that didn't clear up the error.

A search here has a lot of questions about what characters must be escaped but don't seem to pertain to this or even how you might escape them. lol

Comment: `onclick='$("#menu-close").click();'>` Single quotes as the expression uses double quotes

Comment: Ah! Never would have guessed that.

Comment: Dreamweaver does say this now: the value of attribute [onClick] must be closed by double quotes.

Does this mean I can swap them around?

Comment: ```onclick="$('#menu-close').click();"```

Comment: Then `onclick="$('#menu-close').click();">`

Comment: Thanks again, tried it with success. Is this a hard fast rule of javascript or just the application being picky?

Comment: If the value of an attribute like `onClick` contains quotes, you must quote that value using the "other" quotes, otherwise you would have something like `x="A"B"C"` - which is illegal as when the browser tries to interpret `x` how does it know when the value ends? after `A` or after `C`? - `x="A'B'C"` removes this ambiguity (as does `x='A"B"C'`).

Comment: Bitching about "must be closed by double quotes" is a Dreamweaver thing, (matched) single or double quotes are perfectly fine according to the standard.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Dreamweaver can be bitchy sometimes and I never know if I should listen or not.